# PHP: 'syntax error, unexpected T_STRING' with mail()

Tags: php, forms, html-email

I have a simple script that just mails with PHP:

```
mail( "$webmaster_email", "RSVP from WC Entry Form",
   "From: $email, \n Name: $firstname $lastname \n 
   Phone Number: $phone \n 
   Address: $postal \n );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
```

But I am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`

I'm not sure what this is a Googles not giving me any clear answers

Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mail( "$webmaster_email", "RSVP from WC Entry Form",
   "From: $email, \n Name: $firstname $lastname \n 
   Phone Number: $phone \n 
   Address: $postal \n ");
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
```

You just forgot the ' " '.

Comment: Thanks guys - should have been obvious

Answer (score 2):

Change code to

```
mail( "$webmaster_email", "RSVP from WC Entry Form",
   "From: $email, \n Name: $firstname $lastname \n 
   Phone Number: $phone \n 
   Address: $postal \n ");
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
```